# T-SQL: Alter View

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alter

I have a view with a field for date as a varchar. I need to change it to date time using the following code

```
    CONVERT(DATETIME, MyDates)
```

This works fine when executing the view but I want to make the change permanent. I need some help with the syntax. So far I have

```
    ALTER VIEW tableName
    CONVERT(DATETIME, MyDates)
```

but it's obviously not working

Comment: A *view* is only a stored query - it has no columns per se, you cannot alter a view other than changing the query that gets executed ...

Comment: Are you trying to alter the view or to change the column's data type in the underlying table?

Comment: Can you show your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view only fetches the data from the table as per the query.So you cannot change the datatype of the view. you have to change it in table.

Answer (score 4):

Since a view (unless it's a materialized/indexed view which has some extra peculiarities) is more or less just a stored select query, what you do is to just change the select query and alter the view using that.

For example, if you have the view;

```
CREATE VIEW testview AS 
  SELECT id, value FROM test;
```

...where value is a varchar and you want it to be reflected in the view as a datetime, you can just issue;

```
ALTER VIEW testview AS
  SELECT id, CAST(value AS DATETIME) value FROM test;
```

...to make it appear as a datetime in the view.

[An SQLfiddle with a simple demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5219/2).